# What is the best practice of handling different data types in byte buffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

So I have time series that I store packets like this sequence:

**First Packet:**

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();

        ByteBuffer bt = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
...
    bt.putChar('X');
    bt.putChar('X');
    bt.putChar('X');
    bt.putChar('X');
    bt.putChar('E');
    bt.putLong(new Date().getTime());
    bt.putDouble(0.8546324324234d);
```

**Second Packet:**

```
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('E');
bt.putLong(new Date().getTime());
bt.putDouble(0.8546324324234d);
```

**nTh Packet:**

```
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('X');
bt.putChar('E');
bt.putLong(new Date().getTime());
bt.putDouble(0.8546324324234d);
```

As you see all packets has the same sequence, but I have a case that  I receive random String between two packet time to time:

```
bt.putChar('R');
bt.putChar('A');
bt.putChar('N');
bt.putChar('D');
```

So I think I should use some kind of Byte Order Mark as leading bytes to annotate this String. Something like that:

```
public static final byte[] BYTE_MARK = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

But it can be recognized as double 0.0 value as well. What is your suggestion or the best practice that I can mark this String so it can be separated from packets?

Comment: Make all the formats the same, such that when you store the random String you also store the integer and the double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *normal* practice is, to start your various packets with a type marker and eventually length information. Have a look at the package definition for TCP/IP as an example.

The *best* practive is very subjective. My personal best would be, not to care about this low-level-stuff at all, and serialize well-formed objects (one for your 5 chars with long and double, one for your in-between-string.)

Comment: thanks I will check the TCP/IP type markers, I dont prefer Serialization for my case but if I would I think I would change all structure and use proto buffers

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's better if you create a class to model your data

```
class Packet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -603367644775755382L;

    public static final int SIZE = 512;

    private boolean isRandomString;

    private int dataSize;

    private byte[] data;

    public Packet(boolean isRandomString, byte[] data) {
        this.isRandomString = isRandomString;
        this.dataSize = data.length;
        this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, SIZE);
    }
}
```

Put your data to ByteBuffer as byte array serialized from Packet object. And you should deserialized it when getting data. This way you could easily check if it's random string or not.